# Decimal point counter?

Tags: c++

I made this counter but it didn't work and i really don't know how to fix it ..
the counter is supposed to do the next steps:

```
a=1/1.5=0.66
a=0.66/1.49=0.44
a=0.44/1.48=0.29
```

So the final "a" should be 0.29 but the decimal point counter isn't working correctly , here's my code

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string test="aaa";
    double i,j;
    double a=1.0;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < test.size(); j++)
    {
        for ( i = 1.5;i > 0.0;i = i - 0.01)
        {
            while (test[j] == 'a')
            {
                a=a/i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    cout <<"a="<<a<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

how can i fix the decimal point counter to make it decrease by 0.01 with every single character in the string?

Comment: Protip: make sure you properly indent your code

Comment: What does it do now that you believe to be incorrect?

Comment: This code gives me 5.36191e+111 result?

Comment: while it should be .29

Comment: First of all, your initial assumptions are incorrect. If you round to the nearest with 2 decimals, `1/1.5` is `0.67`. `1/1.5/1.49` is `0.45`. And `1/1.5/1.49/1.48` is `0.30`

Comment: jcaron yeah you're right my bad, what about the next step to fix the counter?

Comment: What is a 'decimal point counter'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many loops in your code. You can just use a single `for` loop and within the loop:

1. test if the indexed character in the string is `a`
2. if so, perform the computation

This leads to something along the lines of:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::string test = "aaa";
    double a=1.0;
    for (std::size_t j = 0; j < test.size(); ++j) {
        if (test[j] == 'a') {
            a /= (1.5 - 0.01 * j);
            std::cout << "a=" << a << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbe3bd24d3247734)

To further explain this row:

```
a /= (1.5 - 0.01 * j);
```

You should see your computation as:

```
a = 1    / (1.5 - 0.01 * 0) = 0.66
a = 0.66 / (1.5 - 0.01 * 1) = 0.44
a = 0.44 / (1.5 - 0.01 * 2) = 0.30
```

which is:

```
a = 1    / (1.5 - 0)    = 0.66
a = 0.66 / (1.5 - 0.01) = 0.44
a = 0.44 / (1.5 - 0.02) = 0.30
```

The above code will produce:

> a=0.666667
>
> a=0.447427
>
> a=0.302316

Comment: @user3803421 Are you sure you are using the above code? I've added a live demo that shows that the code compiles and runs just fine.

Comment: i'll flag your answer in a minute

Answer (score 0):

I'm a moment too slow, but here's a similar solution to the one Jeffrey gave:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int, char**)
{
    string test="aaa";

    double i = 1.5;
    double a = 1.0;

    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < test.length(); ++j)
    {
        a = a / i;

        i -= 0.01;  
    }

    cout << "a=" << a << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The result is something along the lines of 0.302316

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what i wanted the last answer directly